# Aandroi: display text over camerapreview

Tags: android, eclipse, textbox, android-camera, overlay

I'm trying to display text over a camera preview.  Right now I have a full screen camera preview, I just can't get text to go overtop of it.

```
<LinearLayout 

   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:baselineAligned="false"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >

   <FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

   </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>enter code here
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a RelativeLayout instead of a LinearLayout? So you can place the items "freely" on top of each other

Comment: yes, but then I can't figure out how to make the camera preview appear full screen